# Fixing elements below a sticky element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4. I have a **header**, below it a **navbar** which is *sticky top*. Below I have a **row** of *2 columns*. In left column, I want the **header to stay fixed below the navbar** when the user scrolls. Same for the right column, I want it to **remain fixed below the navbar**. I also want it to work on small viewport where navbar is **uncollapsed**.

Here is the running example:
https://www.codeply.com/go/Z2DvfjYF0j

Comment: maybe also give "position: sticky" to the header?

Comment: Probably a position sticky with a margin top on the subsequent non sticky content

Comment: For the collapsed menu I think you should use some javascript to move your element just after collapse div or by default move it there and add some padding margin customized

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<h3 class="bg-primary" id="MyStickeHeader">Header</h3>
```

CSS :

```
#MyStickeHeader{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.5rem;
}
```

This is [demo](https://www.bootply.com/6MXcWVke77) link

Comment: How to make the header sticky also when navbar uncollapsed on small viewport?

Comment: @EddyG it's fully responsive. I tested it just a second ago and it still sticky. on the website I gate it's link click on "Mobile" icon and you can test it on other resolutions.

Comment: try the following on small resolution: click on hamburger button, the unordered list shows, but when you scroll the header scrolls, it is not fixed under the navbar if the navbar is uncollapsed.

Comment: dude I searched a lot for you and asked many people. AFAIK unfortunately you can't do this with pure `CSS` you should do this with `JS` by editing `Click` event on your navbar and changing your sticky element with `onClick` function. I hope this information help you. if it does please mark as "best" or at least "up vote" my answer please.